# Mount external drive via sshfs and make it act like a USB drive

Tags: linux, ssh, usb, sshfs, banshee

### My Situation

Arch linux

HTC Nexus one, cyanognmod 7.1

### This is what I want to do:

My android phone has an SSH server.
I use SSHFS to mount my android phone as a drive.
I want Banshee Media Player to recognize that drive as a media drive, so I can do wireless syncing.

### What Works

Mounting Android phone with SSHFS and using it.

### What isn't working

Banshee doesn't recognize the drive as a portable media device, and yes I have a file `.is_audio_player`

### So Far

I read somewhere that Banshee only sees USB drives.

### My Question

How can I make the external drive act as a "virtual" usb drive (just like an optical drive for mounting iso files).

Comment: I had a genius idea. I plugged in an empty usb drive. And i mounted my android phone on that usb. Everything works now. Still not quite what i wanted but it is a start

Comment: Sounds like a banshee bug.